# ClassNotFound exception when setting applicationIdSuffix on debug build

Tags: android, gradle

I'm getting a `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mypackage.myapp.dev.BuildConfig
```

This happens when I set `applicationIdSuffix ".dev"` on my app's `build.gradle`

The Exception makes sense since the build script is generating BuildConfig in the wrong path:

`android/build/generated/source/buildConfig/iap_google/debug/com/mypackage/myapp/BuildConfig.java`

Instead of inside `com/mypackage/myapp/dev`, why?

More info:

- My AndroidManifest's `package="com.mypackage.myapp"`
- My build.gradle's    `applicationId "com.mypackage.myapp"`

I tried removing the Manifest's package attribute to see if BuildConfig is generated in the right place, figured it would use the applicationIdSuffix but no, the build fails with:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:generateIap_googleDebugBuildConfig'.
> Cannot read packageName from .../android/AndroidManifest.xml
```

Any ideas here? :)

Comment: I know this was a long time ago, but I'm having the same issue. Was it ever resolved?